# Office Word reader (viewer, previewer) for Mac OS

Tags: osx, microsoft-word, office

Is there a reader that can open all Word formats and can also remember last used settings when closed?

This one is important because Mac's native preview software always opens on half the screen (this is especially frustrating on 11 inch macbook air). I want it to alway open in full size window. And if it can zoom in, that would be nice.